# What 's wrong with the below code. I am getting Runtime Error

Tags: c++, c++14

I was trying to find the Maximum average marks of student in 2D vector of string. After compilation i am getting Runtime error.

For Eg . The Average Marks of students are : James 80 , Nick 65 , Amit 50 , Fernando 40.
Now the maximum Average among them are James 80

Is there any issue inside Lambda function ?
Why is the below program Crashing?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  vector<vector<string> > vect{{"James", "70"}, {"Fernando", "40"},
                               {"Nick", "60"},  {"James", "90"},
                               {"Nick", "70"},  {"Amit", "50"}};

  auto it = max_element(vect.cbegin(), vect.cend(),
                        [](auto const& left, auto const& right) {
                          return stoi(left[1]) < stoi(left[2]);
                        });

  cout << (*it)[0] << " : " << (*it)[1] << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Expected output : James 80

Comment: You mean `James 90`?

Comment: Please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Did you mean `return stoi(left[1]) < stoi(right[1]);`?

Comment: James Average is (90 + 70)/2= 80 Which is maximum.

Comment: But you're not calculating or printing any average?

Comment: @user8736236 What does average have to do with anything? You are trying to print the maximum element. Anyway Daniel has told you the answer.

Comment: You cannot do this by `std::max_element` alone. First, you need to calculate average values (for instance, by using some associative container) and then find the maximum.

Comment: What kind of runtime error? Your debugger will most likely tell you what's wrong with your code or at least where the error lies.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.Can you please help me to get the maximum average among all. My code is not calculating any average. Please help me to get the maximum Average. Please provide me the sample code

Comment: @nada To be fair, the OP does use `std::stoi` so they do understand that bit.

Comment: @user8736236 StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. You should try something first by yourself and then ask if you run into troubles. I gave you a hint how to proceed.

Comment: `std::vector<std::string>` is a fairly terrible type for holding the marks for a student. Can you not write use `struct Student { std::string name; int mark; };`?

Comment: I can do it other way as well but how can we do it using the above input

Answer (score 4):

You have two small issues in your lambda. First (and as noted in the comments), it should compare `left` and `right`, not `left` and `left`. Second, the indices are incorrect - `left[2]` is an out of bounds access which yields undefined behavior. You can fix both with this:

```
[](auto const& left, auto const& right)
    { return stoi(left[1]) < stoi(right[1]); }
    //                            ^^^^^ ^
```

Comment: Thanks i got the issue now. Can you please help me to get the Maximum Average among all student. for eg. James Average is (90 + 70)/2= 80 Which is maximum